# Prove for some function $\forall x\in\mathbb R, f(x)=0$.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, uniform-convergence

> Let $f(x)$ be some function defined in all of $\mathbb R$. Let $g_{n}(x)=f(\frac{x}{n})$ for any $x\in\mathbb R,n\in\mathbb N$.
>   Suppose $g_{n}(x)$ uniformlly converges to $h(x)\equiv 0$ in $\mathbb R$.
>   Prove that $\forall x\in\mathbb R, f(x)=0$.

My proof goes like this:

Assume that $\exists x_{0}\in\mathbb R, f(x_{0})\neq0$.

Since $g_{n}(x)$ uniformlly converges to $0$, then for $\varepsilon=|f(x_{0})|$,

$\exists N\in\mathbb N,\forall n>N \land \forall x\in\mathbb R, |g_{n}(x)|<\varepsilon$.

Then surely for $x_{1}=(N+1)x_{0}$, we get $|g_{N+1}(x_{1})|=|f(x_{0})|<\varepsilon$, which is a contradiction to our assumption.

Is this a valid proof?

Comment: Looks good to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your proof is correct. I would not have defined $x_1$; instead, I would just have written that$$\bigl|g_{N+1}\bigl((N+1)x_0\bigr)\bigr|=\bigl|f(x_0)\bigr|.$$But that is a matter of taste.